# LuaTeX: Split path string for use in macros

Tags: luatex, strings, split

I would like to parse a path in Lua in order to split it into its folder and file components. The goal is to create a macro that accepts an argument of the form `myfolder/myfile` and be able to use `myfolder`inside the lua block in order to put it into other macros.

The following does not work but is supposed to showcase what I seek:

```
\newcommand*{\splitme}[1]{\directlua{
    local parts=split(#1,'[\\/]+');
    tex.sprint("\graphicspath{",parts[1],"}");
}}
```

I checked out http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin but could not piece it together in LuaLaTeX. Is it possible though without too much hassle?

Comment: Can we assume we are simply splitting at the _last_ `/` char? If so, `string.match` is likely the way to go

Comment: you don't actually need lua for this of course, latex already has in the format `\filename@parse` which is used all over the graphics package to split a filename into directory, basename and extension parts.

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, that was my intention. Henry Menke has actually used `string.match` in his answer...

Comment: @David: Thanks for the hint. I just tried looking into `\filename@parse`, but find it very hard to understand its usage.

Comment: @FlorianL I added an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such cases StackOverflow can be helpful.

```
\documentclass{article}

% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243179
\newcommand*{\splitme}[1]{\directlua{\unexpanded{
    local parts = string.match([[#1]], "(.-)([^\\/]-)$")
    tex.sprint(parts)
    %tex.sprint("\graphicspath{",parts,"}")
}}}

\begin{document}

\splitme{/home/user/test.jpg}

\splitme{/home/user/}

\splitme{/home/user}

% Print the backslash
\def\\{\textbackslash}

\splitme{C:\\home\\user\\test.jpg}

\splitme{C:\\home\\user\\}

\splitme{C:\\home\\user}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not very familiar with lua nor LuaLaTeX here is some lua code, which should return the substring:

```
local i = 0
local p = 0
while i <= in_string:len() do
    if in_string:sub(i,i) == "/" then
        p = i
    end
    i = i + 1
end
return in_string:sub(0,p)
```

There might be a much simpler solution making use of the capabilities of lua, but since I don't know these, this is what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need `/` (and you shouldn't ever need `\` as a path separator in latex) then the format already has a filename parser for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\splitme[1]{\filename@parse{#1}\filename@area}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\splitme{/home/user/test.jpg}

\splitme{/home/user/}

\splitme{/home/user}


\end{document}
```

Comment: With the difference this is not expandable.

Comment: @egreg well true but lots of things aren't expandable:-) (actually it could be expandable, or defined by `directlua` since it is definable in `texsys.cfg` at format time.:-)