# LuaLaTeX: Extract basename from path

Tags: macros, luatex, strings

My question is closely related to [LuaTeX: Split path string for use in macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357246/70340). However, in contrast to this, I would like to have the ***basename***. For example, I am interested in `file` from `/path/to/file.ext` or `path/to/file`.

Using Tex's `\filename@parse` from [Extract filename from path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325046/70340) was not possible. The command is not defined. Maybe that's because I am using LuaLaTex.

So, I tried to adapt the Lua-approach. Based on https://github.com/Donearm/scripts/blob/master/lib/basename.lua, I modified the upper code to (note the additionally escaped `%`):

```
\newcommand*{\basename}[1]{\directlua{\unexpanded{
    local name = string.gsub([[#1]], "(.*/)(.*)", "\%2")
    tex.sprint(name)
}}}
\basename{/path/to/file.ext}
```

Unfortunately, It does not output anything!?!

Comment: `\filename@parse` is defined in lualatex.

Comment: you need to use `\@percentchar`, `\%` does not expand to a `%` token.

Comment: I didn't get it running with `\@percentchar`. Anyway, I use `\filename@parse` now because of its potential backwards compatibility to pdflatex. I have no idea what was wrong with my first implementation. If you post it as an answer I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: I found out why it was not working before. I used it as `\tikzsetnextfilename{\filename@parse\filename@base}`. Since `\tikzsetnextfilename` uses `\filename@parse` for its own it has to be `\filename@parse\tikzsetnextfilename{\filename@base}` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\filename@parse` is defined in lualatex, the example document that you reference at

[Extract filename from path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325046/70340)

gives the same results in pdflatex or lualatex.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get the basename in LuaTeX using the FFI and a platform-dependent function.  On POSIX-based systems you can use the [`basename()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) function.

Because it uses the FFI you have to enable `--shell-escape`.

In `tex.sprint` I use the first argument `-2` to switch to verbatim catcodes, in case the path contains any characters which are treated special by TeX, such as `{}$%#`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
local ffi = assert(require("ffi"))

ffi.cdef[[
char *basename(char *path);
]]

function basename(path)
    local cstr = ffi.new("char[?]", #path + 1)
    ffi.copy(cstr, path)
    return ffi.string(ffi.C.basename(cstr))
end
```

```
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand*\basename[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(-2, basename("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}"))}}
\begin{document}
\basename{/path/to/file.ext}
\end{document}
```